# apache rewrite rule to add www

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I've added a rule to force www in front of my domain name:

browsing to mysite.fr redirects to www.mysite.fr//

why does it add two slashes at the end of the URL ?

Here's my full rewrite rules set:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On  

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.fr
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.fr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule ^/css(/|$) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/img(/|$) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/js(/|$) - [L,NC]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, (its not tested)

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: sorry, it DOES work. (browser cache tricked me). Thanks a lot!